# how to initialize each rows in jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use jquery's function each, but it olny works oonly on one subPage.
For example i have a 70 records, separated by 10 rows at page. After then i change second subpage , all the rows are not initialized.

part of my code:

```
$('select[name=status]').each(function() {
   a = $(this);
   setLead(a);
});
```

Thx for help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in `setLead`?

Comment: setLead is my fuction, which adds options to select.

Comment: So where does the rows get initialized? You wrote "_all the rows are not initialized_" - initialized how and then? No one is able to _guess_ what exactly you are trying to do.